# running a JNI-based .jar on JVM

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

I have a java program i wrote which uses some native methods via JNI.  my java code basically implements a GUI to call native methods from my .dll.  everything seems to work fine when i run the code from my IDE (netbeans), but when i try to run the .jar file it doesn't seem to be able to access the .dll methods.

i've compiled the java program with the 32-bit library for compatibility reasons (even though i am running a 64-bit version of windows7).  i tried running the .jar with the 32-bit java platform but the GUI didn't even display like it normally would using the 64-bit version.  i'm also just using the "system.loadlibrary" command so the .dll path should be relative.

the error i get is "can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform ... blah blah".  when i run from the 32-bit version of java it says "unable to access jarfile ...".  is there any way around this?  the fact that the program runs from my ide makes me think there should be a way to to this.  ideally i'd want my program to run on 32-bit machines as well so i don't want to make the program 64-bit.

also, the compiler throws the warning "bootstrap classpath not set in conjunction with source 1.6", but i'm not sure if this has anything to do with my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system property `java.library.path` defines the paths that Java looks at when loading libraries with `System.loadLibrary()`.  On Windows, by default this will have the current directory (i.e. the directory the app was started from) as well as the JRE bin directory and Windows' system32 directory.

You could try putting the arguments `-Djava.library.path=<path to your DLL file>` when you start up the JVM and see if that makes a difference.

You can also force load a library file using an absolute path using `System.load()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried copying the .dll to the windows/system32 directory

No.

> the java/jdk1.7.0/bin directory

Should have worked, but the wrong place.

> and to the same directory as the .jar

No.

The best place for JNI DLLs is in the current directory when you execute the JAR file.

> but none of these fixed the problem.

Which problem is that? You haven't provided the error message yet.

Comment: @Ben If you weren't finding the DLL or a method in it an exception is thrown. Find it and post it.